# Accessing oracle from Tomcat resource, why am I getting a NamingException?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jndi

Trying to expose an Oracle connection through tomcat Context.xml, I get a NamingException.  I've followed several tutorials, but I'm still getting the exception.  Help!

Java:

```
String environmentLookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/ENTERPRISE_DATABASE";
OracleDataSource ods = InitialContext.doLookup(environmentLookup);
Connection connection = ods.getConnection();
```

App's web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/ENTERPRISE_DATABASE</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ENTERPRISE_DATABASE" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.Datasource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@enterprise.db.company.com:1524:schema1234"
    username="ENTERPRISE_USER" password="ENTERPRISE_PASSWORD" maxActive="20"
    maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

The Exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:144)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
```

Comment: Is `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` on Tomcat's classpath?

Comment: I believe so; the driver is in the /lib/ directory for TC.  How can I check for sure?

Comment: Is the stacktrace complete? Doesn't look so, I would expect some "caused by" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type="javax.sql.Datasource"
```

Should be

```
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```